# Hive query with RANK() in a WHERE clause

Tags: hive

I want to do this, to get all the rows for a given `a,b` combo that have the highest value of `c`:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM x
WHERE RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a,b ORDER BY c DESC) = 1
```

It fails, saying `invalid column reference 'c': (possible column names are: a, b, c)`.

I can wrap the RANK() in a subselect, and check the value outside:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a,b ORDER BY c DESC) AS r
  FROM x
) rq
WHERE r = 1
```

Any idea why I can't do this in the WHERE clause of the simple query? Is it because of it being an aggregate/window function, so has to be done after the `WHERE`, like a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: `SELECT a, b, MAX(c) FROM x GROUP BY a,b` ?

Comment: *why I can't do this in the WHERE clause of the simple query?* The order of WHERE sub-conditions execution is not defined. So, when window function executing before and after another conditions applying, the frames (source data sub-arrays) will differ. So window function cannot posess in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Akina A simple MAX() would not return multiple records.

Comment: Do you need a pack of full duplicates really? It's more simple to add COUNT(*) into output list and generate proper record copies on the client side...

Comment: Yes I do need the duplicates.

Comment: If so use subselect-wrapping query (or use CTE).